# Remove repeatable job in Bull

Tags: typescript, cron, scheduled-tasks, nestjs

I am using `queue.removeRepeatable()` to remove specific repeatable jobs from my queue, but it does not give me the status of whether the job has been removed, or it failed to do so.

**Controller to remove job**

```
//here id is the name of the job
@Post('/remove/:id')
async removeRepeat(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() repeatOptions) {
    try {
        const removed = await this.queue.removeRepeatable(
            id,
            repeatOptions,
        );
        console.log('Removed');
        return removed;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this issue, so that I can get to know if something went wrong?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Let's say if I pass a wrong ID. In that case, it does not throw an error and simply returns a void Pointer. I wanted to know if there's a way to catch the error

Comment: if `this.queue.removeRepeatable()` is not throwing an Error, then your try/catch is not going to work. You could check if `removed` is defined after, and if not, throw an Error.

Comment: `removed` always comes out to be`undefined` no matter what

Comment: In that case, make `removeRepeatable()` return a value or, if it's from an extern library, check if `this.queue` still contains the entry after the method.